# Need urgent help in fixing soft-bricked Moto G5s

Tags: root-access, fastboot, unbricking, motorola-moto-g, stock-rom

I was trying to root my Moto G5s. I did a mistake while flashing twrp, I flashed cedric instead of montana. As a result, whenever I reboot, I am getting error:

```
    Start Up Failed:
Your device didn't start up successfully. Use the Software Repair Assistant on computer to repair your device
```

And the FastBoot terminal kind of thing that appears below shows

```
Error: Failed to load kernel
Boot up failed
```

I downloaded a boot.img of stock rom but don't know how to flash it. I tried using command

```
fastboot boot boot.img
```

This boots up to stock rom but whenever I restart, I get same error. Also when I boot with that image, my wifi doesn't work. Can someone please help me. It is urgent as I don't have another mobile.

Comment: Why don't you boot directly into the correct TWRP using fastboot? Run `fastboot boot YOUR_CORRECT_TWRP.img`. From there, flash the correct recovery, and if needed, correct boot image too. Also, note that we are  volunteers here. So, please don't expect  urgent help.

Comment: @Firelord can you please tell me any site to get latest Moto G5s stock rom. its name is montana